# Conditional time formatting Java

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat, datetime-format, gregorian-calendar

I'm trying to use Javas `GregorianCalendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`classes to create Time Series.

The raw data that I'm using is in simple epoch format (Unix time) and I translate all of these timestamps into readable time and dates.

However, If I have a time series that range from say 23.00 to 01.00 (i.e the date changes somewhere in the middle) I would like my output to reflect that.

Example:

```
{"23.00", "23.30", "00.00 2015-08-12", "00.30", "01.00"}
```

Do you know if there is some support for this in `SimpleDateFormat`, or anything I can do to automate this process?

Thanks!

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` (and similar) only works with one date at a time, how is it supposed to be aware that the day has changed? Use two `SimpleDateFormat` and control the change of day yourself.

Comment: @Joakim Single call to any Date-formatter has no knowledge if it is first after midnight. You MUST USE external code to represent this fact. BTW be careful with time zone etc.

Comment: Juan excuse my not so fluent English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some sample code to work with.  The key bits are using the `Calendar` class to track changes in the date.  This outputs:

```
{"23.00", "23.30", "00.00 2015-08-12", "00.30", "01.00", "01.30"}
```

Code:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class TS {

    // 11PM 2015-08-12
    long base=1439348420L; 

    long[] timestamps = {
        base,
        base + 1800,
        base + 1800*2,
        base + 1800*3,
        base + 1800*4,
        base + 1800*5
    };

    // MAKE SURE THIS IS IN THE RIGHT TIMEZONE
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int lastday;
    static DateFormat HHMM = new SimpleDateFormat("\"HH.mm\"");
    static DateFormat DATE_HHMM = new SimpleDateFormat("\"HH.mm yyyy-MM-dd\"");

    public void run() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("{");
        for (int i=0; i<timestamps.length; i++) {
            if (i>0) sb.append(", ");
            sb.append(formattedDate(timestamps[i]));
        }
        sb.append('}');
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }

    public String formattedDate(long unixtime) {
        String result = null;
        cal.setTimeInMillis(unixtime*1000);

        int today = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        if (today != lastday && lastday > 0) {
            result = DATE_HHMM.format(cal.getTime());
        } else {
            result =  HHMM.format(cal.getTime());
        }
        lastday = today;
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TS ts = new TS();
        ts.run();
    }

}
```